# Distance between point and line in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Let $a,b$ be fixed complex numbers and let $L$ be the line
$$L=\{a+bt:t\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Let $w\in\Bbb C\setminus L$. Let's calculate $$d(w,L)=\inf\{|w-z|:z\in L\}=\inf_{t\in\Bbb R}|w-(a+bt)|.$$
The first observation is
$$d(w,L)=\inf_{t\in\Bbb R}|w-(a+bt)|=\inf_{t\in\Bbb R}|(w-a)-bt|=d(w-a,L-a).$$
So without loss of generality we can assume that $a=0$, so
$$L=b\Bbb R.$$
And then, let's assume that $|b|=1$.

Assume
$$b=x+iy,\qquad x,y\in\Bbb R,$$
and let
$$b'=y-ix.$$
so that $b'\bar{b}$ is purely imaginary and $|b'|=|b|=1$.

Consider the line
$$L'=w+b'\Bbb R.$$
Then $L$ and $L'$ are orthogonal and since $w=w+b'\cdot 0$ we get $w\in L'$. Let $w'$ the point in which these lines meet. Let's calculate it
$$\begin{align*}
w+b's &= bs\\
s &= \frac{w}{b-b'}.
\end{align*}$$
so $w'=w+b's$. The distance $d(w,L)$ must be achieved at $w'$ (because $L'$ is the perpendicular line to $L$ through $w$), so
$$d(w,L)=|w-w'|=|b's|=1|s|=\left|\frac{w}{b-b'}\right|=\frac{|w|}{|b-b'|}.$$
Let's compute $|b-b'|$
$$|b-b'|^2=|x+iy-(y-ix)|^2=(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2=2|b|^2=2$$
therefore
$$d(w,L)=\frac{|w|}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
What I have just proved is equivalent to say that the triangle with vertex $0$, $w$, $w'$ is isosceles rectangle, regardless of the line through the origin and the $w$. Of course this is absurd but,

**What is wrong with the above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calculating where the points meet, you set $w+b's=bs$. This a mistake, you should set that $w+b's=bt$ where $s$ does not necessarily equal $t$, but both are real.  The point you calculate is a point equidistant from $0$ and $w$ of distance $|s|$ . Because, for example, $$d(w,w+b's) = |b's|=|s|=|bs|=d(0,bs).$$

Note that doing it your original way, $s$ is not necessarily real, so the point may not even lie on either of the lines! (And probably won't!)

Note: To solve $w+b's=bt$, equate real and imaginary parts to get a pair of simultaneous equations to solve.

In addition, doing the problem this way seems a little overcomplicated. Further, you assert that the distance is minimised by connecting $w$ to $L$ perpendicularly, which should be rigorously proven. A much quicker way is to simply calculate $$\inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\{|w-bt|\}=\inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\{((w_1-xt)^2+(w_2-yt)^2)^\frac12\}$$ which is achieved by finding the value of $t$ minimising the function $$f(t) = (w_1-xt)^2+(w_2-yt)^2,$$ which is a quadratic.

Comment: @Leo No problem! Happy to help! I just edited my answer to provide a slightly faster, more rigorous way to solve the problem, if you're interested.

Comment: To justify my method one can argue that $w'$ is the orthogonal projection of $w$ over $L$. Anyway your approach seems indeed simpler. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

"$w + b's = bs$" is this your problem? A solution to this doesn't tell you where the lines meet. Because $|b| = |b'| = 1$, you're in fact just finding a point $w'$ that's a distance $s$ away from $w$ (in the direction $b'$) and a distance $s$ away from $0$ (in the direction $b$). No wonder $(0, w, w')$ is isosceles and right-angled!

Answer (score 1):

$\renewcommand\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\renewcommand\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$
For the sake of completeness, let's finish the derivation of the formula.

I'll follow the notation used in my question.

Let's think in $\Bbb C$ as a real inner product space with inner product
$$\langle z,w\rangle=\Re (z\bar{w}).$$

From the fact $\langle z,w\rangle=0$ and that the dimension of $\Bbb C$ as vector space over $\Bbb R$ is 2, it follows that
$$L^\perp=b'\Bbb R.$$

Thus $\Bbb C=L^\perp\oplus L$, i.e. there are $s,t$ real numbers such that
$$\begin{align*}
w &= b's+w'\\
&= b's+bt.
\end{align*}$$

Let's calculate the orthogonal projection $w'=bt$ of $w$ over $L$. It is know that
$$|w-w'|\leq |w-z|\quad\forall z\in L.$$

Assume $$w=w_1+iw_2\quad w_1,w_2\in\Bbb R.$$

Then, from $$w_1+iw_2=(y-ix)s+(x+iy)t$$ we get the system
$$\begin{cases}
ys+xt = w_1\\
-xs+yt = w_2
\end{cases}$$
Using Cramer's rule:
$$s=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix} w_1 & x\\ w_2 & y\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} y & x\\ -x & y\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{w_1y-w_2x}{|b|^2}=\frac{w_1y-w_2x}{1}=-\Im (w\bar{b}).$$

Therefore $$w'=w-b's=w+b'\Im (w\bar{b}).$$ So
$$d(w,L)=|w-w'|=|-b'\Im (w\bar{b})|=|b'||\Im (w\bar{b})|=|\Im (w\bar{b})|.$$

Now, if we consider $L$ in its general form $L=a+b\Bbb R$, we get
$$d(w,L)=\left|\Im \left((w-a)\bar{b}\right)\right|.$$