# Proof of equation of complex number equation of parabola

Tags: complex-numbers

How does one derive equation of parabola using complex numberS? I'm talking about of stuff like the representation of circle using complex numbers $|z-z_o|=r$

Edit: I figured out distance from point on parabola to focus is |z-z_o| but how does one write distance from parabola to directix

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, to be honest :/

Comment: For example the complex equation of a parabola is  $|z-z_o| = r^2$

Answer (score 0):

Idea: use the fact that a parabola is the locus of points whose distance from a fixed point, say $z_0$, is the same as its distance from a fixed line.

The distance to $z_0$ is easy. For the distance between a point and a line, I suggest reading [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356764/distance-between-point-and-line-in-the-complex-plane).

Comment: the notation hurts my head

Comment: I got distance of point but distance from fixed line part , I'm  confused